# Logic doesn't go to second ElseIf

Tags: vb.net

I have something like this:

```
   If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBeginDate) AndAlso someMoreConditionsHere Then
       If somethingElse Then
            ' Do some work here
       End If
   ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBeginDate) Then
       cell.IsEnabled = False
   ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBeginDate) Then
       cell.IsEnabled = True
   End If
```

In debugging when the `If somethingElse Then` is not correct it correctly goes to

```
ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBeginDate) Then
```

which correctly doesn't go inside it because `selectedBeginDate` does have a value but I am expecting it to go to **next** `ElseIf` but it jumps over it!!!!

**Why?**

Comment: There is no `Else` for the `If SomethingElse`; it ought not go into any of the Else blocks shown once it enters the first

Comment: @Plutonix yep, figured it out. I changed the order and brought up the last two ElseIfs so it checks for them first now.

Comment: Simplify with _cell.IsEnabled = IF(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBeginDate), False, True)_

Comment: Also, consider `Select...Case` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Solution:

```
   If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBeginDate) AndAlso someMoreConditionsHere Then
       If somethingElse Then
            ' Do some work here
       End If
   Else
       cell.IsEnabled = Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedBeginDate) Then
   End If
```